# vue webpack-simple template and Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

Getting a strange error when creating an IIFE method in main.js file. Here are the steps to reproduce it, goto command prompt

```
vue init webpack-simple test
cd test
npm install test
npm run dev
```

Edit main.js file and add this method at the end

```
(function test() {
  console.log('test');
})();
```

It will throw the following error on console

```
Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value) is not a function
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (build.js:978), <anonymous>:13:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:978)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:660)
    at fn (build.js:84)
    at Object.<anonymous> (build.js:1378)
    at __webpack_require__ (build.js:660)
    at build.js:709
    at build.js:712
```

If I make test a normal function and call it like test(), then it does not throw error, why it has issues when creating IIFE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the Vue template does not use semicolons. So you have this code:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})

(function test() {
  console.log('test');
})();
```

But whitespace is insignificant and what you really have is:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})(function test() {
  console.log('test');
})();
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
const vue = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(App)
})

vue(function test() {
  console.log('test');
})();
```

This will give you the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: vue is not a function
```

Which is exactly what you had, but this time `vue` has a name instead of being an intermediate value.

This is one of the cases you need to pay attention to when omitting semicolons.